# How can you show with a diagram that diffraction is at a maximum when the slit width is equal to the wavelength?

Tags: visible-light, waves, double-slit-experiment, diffraction, wavelength

Usually a diagram will be given like this

[image]

But how can you show with a diagram that diffraction can be maximised when the slit width is of the order of the wave's wavelength?

Comment: That diagram does not get the intensities right. That should be a sinc$^2$ function.

Comment: @Pieter I will edit it accordingly. Thank you! How would you answer the original question?

Comment: One could make a plot of the intensity at large angles as a function of slit width, but that does not seem to be an answer to your question. Maybe a drawing with phasor arrows would be helpful, but I do not have an idea for a good sketch.

Comment: How are you defining maximisation of diffraction? Exactly what is at a maximum?

Comment: @PhilipWood the slit width that produces the greatest angle of diffraction (angle from central fringe)

Comment: For slit widths of one wavelength the first minimum for Fraunhofer diffraction is at ±90° to the normal, so the central beam spreads right round, though the intensity falls off as the angle to the normal increases. But if the slit width is less than one wavelength there is also spreading right round, with less fall-off in intensity at the edges.

Answer (score 0):

When the width is equal to the wavelength , the first minimum occurs at 90° or in no direction . just see the difference in ways for two waves from the edges of the slit..
the minimum occurs, when the difference of was of 1/2 of the slit tu the second half iss half a wavelength, this can to happen for any angle below 90°

Comment: why would this happen and how does it relate to wavelength?

Comment: do you know how diffraction pattern are explained, for example where the first Minimum is located? otherwise you have to look it up, the diagram you posted  is very wrong for the drawn wavelength and the pattern,

Comment: I know how they're created, and I should have edited the diagram as a previous comment pointed out. I was looking for a more visual explanation as to why it happens though.

Comment: I edited my answer is it now clear? but diffraction with even smaller slits leaves the opposing wall all illuminated, a smaller slit works almost like a (very weak) point source